# How to wait on completion of a whole chain of Promises in Javascript ECMAScript2015 (es6)

Tags: javascript, concurrency, ecmascript-6

Pretty new to es6 and curious to know whether now with Promises, I can do away with `future.wait()`

I have a method called `execute()`, which starts a chain of promises.  I have two requirements of this method:

- Each promise should only start when the last promise has completed (this part I have achieved)
- `execute()` should only return when the whole chain of promises has completed executing (i.e. I want to block until the last promise is complete)

Here is my sample code:

```
/* Require dependencies */
require('babel/polyfill');

class PromiseWaiter {
  /* Constructor */
  constructor() {
  }

  /* Methods */
  execute() {
    let _this = this;

    runPromiseGenerator(function *promiseGenerator() {
      yield _this.asyncMethod1();
      yield _this.asyncMethod2();
      yield _this.asyncMethod3();
    });

    return true;
  }

  asyncMethod1() {
    return returnDummyPromise('method 1', 800);
  }
  asyncMethod2() {
    return returnDummyPromise('method 2', 200);
  }
  asyncMethod3() {
    return returnDummyPromise('method 3', 200);
  }
}

var runPromiseGenerator = function(generator) {
  var it = generator(), ret;

  // asynchronously iterate over generator
  (function iterate(val) {
    ret = it.next(val);

    if (!ret.done) {
      // poor man's "is it a promise?" test
      if ("then" in ret.value) {
        // wait on the promise
        ret.value.then(iterate);
      }
      // immediate value: just send right back in
      else {
        // avoid synchronous recursion
        setTimeout( function(){
          iterate(ret.value);
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  })();

};

var returnDummyPromise = function(methodName, timeout) {
  console.log('starting %s', methodName);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('finished %s', methodName);
      resolve();
    }, timeout);
  })
};

module.exports = PromiseWaiter;
```

Here is what I run on the node console to test & the current output:

```
> p = new PromiseWaiter()
{}
> p.execute()
starting method 1
true
> finished method 1
starting method 2
finished method 2
starting method 3
finished method 3
```

What I want to see is:

```
> p = new PromiseWaiter()
{}
> p.execute()
starting method 1
finished method 1
starting method 2
finished method 2
starting method 3
finished method 3
true
>
```

In the past I would have done this using

```
fut = new Future();
// set off chain passing future
future.wait();
```

Wanted to pick the brains of the best and brightest out there.

Thanks in advance for your time!
Elliott

Comment: Why re-implement `runPromiseGenerator`? [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) already does it, and it does it with code the handle what you're trying to do. You need `runPromiseGenerator` to return a promise, so you can do `runPromiseGenerator(...).then(function(){ console.log('all done'); });`

Comment: What is that `future.wait()` thing? Fibers? Were you using some specific library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return a promise that will resolve when the generator has completed. I'd really recommend using an existing implementation like [`co`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co) however if you wanted to expand your own implementation:

```
var runPromiseGenerator = function(generator) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var it = generator(), ret;

    // asynchronously iterate over generator
    (function iterate(val) {
      try {
        ret = it.next(val);

        if (!ret.done) {
          Promise.resolve(ret.value).then(iterate, reject);
        }
        else {
          resolve(ret.value);
        }
      }
      catch (e){
        reject(e);
      }
    })();
  });
};
```

then you can alter your `execute` to be

```
execute() {
  let _this = this;

  return runPromiseGenerator(function *promiseGenerator() {
    yield _this.asyncMethod1();
    yield _this.asyncMethod2();
    yield _this.asyncMethod3();
  });
}
```

and do

```
p.execute().then(function(){
  // done
});
```

Alternatively, you can use your existing function to then call it, e.g.

```
runPromiseGenerator(function *promiseGenerator() {
  yield p.execute();

  // do something after execution
});
```

Comment: Thanks for directing me to co - as I said, I'm quite new to es6 and hadn't seen that library.  I understand your suggestion, to return a promise, but that isn't quite what I want.  I'm looking for a way to stop execute from finishing until the promise chain is complete.  I think I'm after the `await` keyword from es7

Comment: No problem, hope this all makes sense.

Comment: There is no way to block execution in JS, but you can use syntax like `yield` or `await` to suspend execution. If you want to execute something after `execute` then you'd have to use `runPromiseGenerator` or `co` just like you are doing already. I added an example to the answer. ES7-proposed `async/await` is essentially exactly what you have already implemented here with generators, except with a new syntax that doesn't need external libraries.